# Creat view with a avg column

Tags: oracle

I need to create a view VIEW UOS_VU_STUDENT_AVERAGE, one of the column requries average GRADE, SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW UOS_VU_STUDENT_AVERAGE AS
SELECT STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME, STUDENT_MODULE.GRADE
FROM STUDENT, STUDENT_MODULE
WHERE STUDENT_ID<120000001
```

How could I avg grade in this sql?

Comment: 1. Create a `select` query that *works* first. 2. `AVG` makes no sense without `GROUP BY` in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "Group by" for any mathematical function like

```
AVG ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )
```

for example ..

```
SELECT id, AVG(salary) from tablename GROUP BY filedname
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
CREATE VIEW UOS_VU_STUDENT_AVERAGE AS
SELECT STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME, avg(STUDENT_MODULE.GRADE)
FROM STUDENT, STUDENT_MODULE
WHERE STUDENT_ID<120000001 
group by STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME
```

as zerkms commented, there is no join condition, you probably need something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW UOS_VU_STUDENT_AVERAGE AS
SELECT STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME, avg(STUDENT_MODULE.GRADE)
FROM STUDENT join STUDENT_MODULE on student_module.STUDENT_ID = student.id
WHERE STUDENT_ID<120000001 
group by STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME
```

(I'm just guessing that the FK is on `student_module.STUDENT_ID = student.id`)

Comment: Just a side note: I understand you've just copied OPs query, but there is no join condition

Comment: @zerkms, yes you're right. It's also not recomended to use the old syntax for joins

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like the following.  I've made a few assumptions on the structure of the tables.

```
CREATE VIEW uos_vu_student_average AS
SELECT first_name, last_name,  AVG(grade) avg_grade
  FROM student, student_module
 WHERE student.student_id = student_module.student_id
   AND student.student_id < 120000001
 GROUP BY first_name, last_name;
```

In your example, and as was pointed out by a previous poster, you don't have a join in your original example so it would just average all the grades together, regardless of the student_id.  The result would show everyone with the same average grade.

When doing aggregate functions inside a view you also need to assign the resulting column an alias, so you can reference it in some manner when performing DML against the view.  In this case I assigned it avg_grade.